# Cluster point and convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. A point $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be a cluster point of $A$ if for all $r>0$ there exists $x\in A$, but $x\neq a$, such that $|x-a|<r$. The question is to show that if $a$ is a cluster point of $A$, then there exists a sequence of points in $A\setminus \{a\}$ that converges to $a$. The proof is available in many places, but I need some understanding here.

Assume $a$ cluster point of $A$. Choose $x_1\in A$, such that $0<|x_1-a|<1$. Choose $x_2\in A$, such that $0<|x_2-a|<1/2$. Choose $x_3\in A$, such that  $0<|x_3-a|<1/3$. Keep doing like this. But ... how can you be sure, that you can *find infinitely* many other points $x_4,x_5,....$ such that  $0<|x_k-a|<1/k$ for $k\geq 4$? This is the problem to my understanding.

Comment: If you couldn't, then it wouldn't be a cluster point

Comment: Explicitly, there would be an $n$ such that $B(a,\frac1n)\cap A = \{x\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$, i.e., $x$ is isolated.